# Can't compare 2 strings - strange errors

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have this code in my procedure:

```
IF old_value_l = new_value_l THEN 
      dummy_val_l := 0;

    ELSIF old_value_l != new_value_l THEN   -- This is line 4019 mentioned in the error
         -- some code here

END IF;
```

But it is throwing some strange errors:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at "DBS.MONITORING", line 4019
ORA-06512: at line 12
```

It clearly says that the number is invalid, but wait a minute, what number?
Both `old_value_l` and `new_value_l` are declared as `VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)`

and here is how:

```
  new_value_l               history.new_value%TYPE;
  old_value_l               history.old_value%TYPE;
```

Why even when both of the variables are declared as `VARCHAR2` it says that the number is invalid?

I know that I'm missing an extremely small part here, but I can't spot it or understand my mistake at this momment.

**EDIT**

Values I'm comparing:

`new_value_l = 15` and `old_value_l = 10`

Comment: Is it possible that you assign some numeric value to one of these variables before this part of code?

Comment: @Guneli Yes it is possible, but if the one is numeric then the other is also numeric(but saved as a string in teh database), the same applies to the strins - if the one is string then the other is also a string.

Comment: Maybe, you should print the values of the variables before comparing. This can give some insight at the nature of the problem.

Comment: @Guneli `new_value_l = 15` and `old_value_l = 10`

Comment: what if you remove the second condition and leave just ELSE? It is the same thing logically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code like this does not tell us they are numbers, it tells that first variable has a type like column new_value in history table, and the second variable has a type like old_value in history table.

```
new_value_l               history.new_value%TYPE;
old_value_l               history.old_value%TYPE;
```

So, you need to:

1. Ensure that both of these columns have the same datatype, VARCHAR2
2. Sometimes errors appear in a line, while actual error is in next or previous line, so you have to check them too
3. Try to check there is no spaces stored in values by using trim

   ```
   ... 
   ELSIF trim(old_value_l) != trim(new_value_l) 
   ...
   ```
4. I think you have to handle null values too.

   ```
   ... 
   ELSIF trim(old_value_l) != trim(new_value_l) 
   ...
   ```

Comment: Though you're not wrong it would be considerably better to just ensure that two columns, which are meant to have identical data types actually have identical data types. Ignoring the problem by making data transformations, while easy, only hides an issue which can bite you hard in the future.

Comment: I just checked and the error was in the code inside of the if satetemnt. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

It will be converted to a number automatically. So, you can test it as per the below:

```
select 1 from dual where '114' >120;
select 1 from dual where '125' >120;
```

You'd better check whether each value has some characters which cannot be converted to a number, such as CRLF.